# How to fix 'System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file'

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

Following code gives me that error "System.IO.IOException: 'The process cannot access the file `'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\exampleText.txt' because it is being used by another process"`
Here is the code:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(regexBox.Text, RegexOptions.Singleline);
            foreach(string file in fileNames)
            {

                var currentFile = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                string[] texts = File.ReadAllLines(currentFile.Name);
                currentFile.Close();

                var match = regex.Matches(texts.ToString())
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Value)
                   .ToArray(); ;
                textBox1.Lines = match;
                Array.Copy(match, myTexts,match.Length);
              }
```

Any idea why I'm getting that error ?

Comment: Because you're opening it with `File.Open`, and then trying to open it a second time with `File.ReadAllLines` without closing the first one?

Comment: You don't need to open and then close the file if you want to use File.ReadAllLines. Just pass the _file_ variable to ReadAllLines